# Android Studio image preview icon in editor sidebar

Tags: android-studio, editor, sidebar

In sidebar editor of Android Studio I have small image preview icons,
but sometimes my images are very long but low, so they fill 3/4 of the screen size.
How to turn off the preview?

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable any of the icons by going to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Gutter Icons and then for disabling the image previews uncheck `icon preview` under java

[image]

Comment: @RadekSołdek Take your time! Make sure to mark this as the answer if it answers your question.